# C++ - Function with multiple parameter packs and a std::function as argument

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I am trying to create an IoC Container in C++ that resolves dependencies automatically.

For that I created a function with two variadic parameter packs that is declared like this:

```
template <class T, typename ... TDependencies, typename... TArgs> 
void Register(std::function<std::shared_ptr<T> (std::shared_ptr<TDependencies> ...,
TArgs ...)> && pFactory)
```

Apparently, it seems the compiler is unable to match this when supplied with

```
Register<Foo, Bar>(std::function<std::shared_ptr<Foo>(std::shared_ptr<Bar>)>(
[](std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar){return std::make_shared<Foo>(bar);}));
```

The compile errors say

```
note: candidate: 'void Container::Register(std::function<std::shared_ptr<_Tp>
(std::shared_ptr<TDependencies>..., TArgs ...)>&&)
[with T = Foo; TDependencies = {Bar}; TArgs = {std::shared_ptr<Bar>}]'
```

Apparently, it matches `std::shared_ptr<Bar>` twice. How can I get the compiler not to match the `shared_ptr` in TArgs too?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<T (std::shared` should be `std::shared_ptr<T>(std::shared` ?

Comment: Yes of course, I messed up when copying.
Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: can you please format your code with a max of 80 characters. Most of your code is hidden and having to horizontally scroll on two instances is very tedious and hard to read.

Comment: The function signature is ambiguous if any of the parameters is itself a shared pointer.

Comment: I hope it looks better like this.
Sadly I have no idea about how to make the signature non-ambiguous since the dependencies have to be shared_pointer arguments of the function

Comment: @Quimby but why? What rules are preventing this template to unambiguously match `TArgs...` as an empty pack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to deduce `TDependencies` directly from the `pFactory` parameter type, I'd write a type trait to get the dependencies from the whole parameter pack instead. With `boost::mp11`:

```cpp
template <class>
struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};

namespace mp11 = ::boost::mp11;

template <class... Ts>
using register_traits = mp11::mp_partition<mp11::mp_list<Ts...>, is_shared_ptr>;

template <class T, class F, class... TDependencies, class... TArgs>
void RegisterImpl(F && pFactory,
                  mp11::mp_list<
                      mp11::mp_list<std::shared_ptr<TDependencies>...>,
                      mp11::mp_list<TArgs...>>);

template <class T, class... Ts> 
void Register(std::function<std::shared_ptr<T> (Ts...)> && pFactory)
{
    return RegisterImpl<T>(
        std::forward<std::function<std::shared_ptr<T> (Ts...)>>(pFactory),
        register_traits<Ts...>{});
}
```

And to call it:

```cpp
Register(std::function{[] (std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar) {
    return std::make_shared<Foo>(bar);
}});
```

[Try it on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/GeMbdoYzG).

If `boost::mp11` is not an option, here's how you can implement your own `partition` template metafunction:

```cpp
template <class...>
struct list {};

namespace detail {
template <class L, template <class...> class P, class T, class F, class = void>
struct partition;

template <class Next, class... Ls,
          template <class...> class P, class T, class... Fs>
struct partition<list<Next, Ls...>, P, T, list<Fs...>,
                 std::enable_if_t<!P<Next>::value>> :
       partition<list<Ls...>, P, T, list<Fs..., Next>> {};

template <class Next, class... Ls,
          template <class...> class P, class... Ts, class F>
struct partition<list<Next, Ls...>, P, list<Ts...>, F,
                 std::enable_if_t<P<Next>::value>> :
       partition<list<Ls...>, P, list<Ts..., Next>, F> {};

template <template <class...> class P, class T, class F>
struct partition<list<>, P, T, F> { using type = list<T, F>; };
} // namespace detail

template <class L, template <class...> class P>
using partition = typename detail::partition<L, P, list<>, list<>>::type;

template <class... Ts>
using register_traits = partition<list<Ts...>, is_shared_ptr>;

template <class T, class F, class... TDependencies, class... TArgs>
void RegisterImpl(F && pFactory,
                  list<list<std::shared_ptr<TDependencies>...>, list<TArgs...>>);
```

[Try it on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/o95xK7jx7).

The rest of the code will remain the same.